# Mediawiki php: how to get the name of user who uploaded a file?

Tags: php, mediawiki

I'm updating a MediaWiki extension that shows all the images in a category ([CategoryGallery](https://m.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryGallery)).

I would like to show the name of the user who uploaded the image and then possibly to filter by user.

A portion of the code is like this:

```
// Capitalize the first letter in the category argument, convert spaces to _
$params['cat'] = str_replace ( ' ', '_', ucfirst( $params['cat'] ) );

// Retrieve category members from database
$dbr = wfGetDB( DB_SLAVE );
$res = $dbr->select( 'categorylinks', 'cl_from',
array ('cl_to' => $params['cat'],
                           'cl_type' => 'file'));
$ids = array();

foreach ( $res as $row ) {
    $ids[] = $row->cl_from;
}

// Create the gallery
$titles = Title::newFromIDs ( $ids );
$text = '';

foreach ( $titles as $title ) {
    $titlePrefixedDBKey = $title->getPrefixedDBKey();
    $text .= $titlePrefixedDBKey;
    $text .= "|**Username**:\n";
}

$output = $parser->renderImageGallery( $text, $params )
```

How can I retrieve the name of the user who uploaded the photo to show it in the image gallery (where I have put **Username**) ?

Comment: `$title->getFirstRevision()->getUserText()`

Comment: Thanks for your help @Tgr!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `$title` variable is a [`Title` object](https://doc.wikimedia.org/mediawiki-core/master/php/classTitle.html). You should be able to use that to get the author of the latest revision:

```
$currentRevID = $title->getLatestRevID();
$revAuthors = $title->getAuthorsBetween($currentRevID, $currentRevID, 1, 'include_both'); //1=limit
$authorName = $revAuthors[0];
```

This uses a function that returns authors between two revisions, but we just pass the current revision as both the min and max revision.

Note that editing the image caption counts as a revision, so it's possible for this code to return the name of a user that didn't upload the file. How likely that is to occur probably depends on how your wiki is used.

Comment: FWIW both this and my code snippet above rest on the assumption that the author of the first revision and the uploader of the file is the same, which can be untrue in exotic circumstances. Not something I'd be worried about, just noting.